# How should i be adding/loading images into my game?

Tags: android, image, textures, libgdx

So, like everyone else, I've been developing a game using libgdx targeting android os. I'd really like to use my personal art(photoshop paintbrush) as opposed to pixel art. Well, actually I'm trying to fuse the 2 because we all know android doesn't accommodate enough memory to display some of the art I'd like to use.

For example: I have many backgrounds that are 512x512 put next to each other to make up the entire "First Stage", seemingly up to 12+ images, and each image is around 100k.  This is taxing on the android and lowers frame rate dramatically, below 30 fps,  rendering me unable to add more images to the scene which I will **need** to do.

Question:  What is **the** way to go about adding "Background" images and background Doodads?

How big in Kb(size) should they not go over?

I'm loading them as a Sprite not a texture, is that good/bad?

Background images are saved as .png 512x512 8bit, is that good/bad what would be better?

Does texturePacker do anything for performance, and should i even texturepack these files that are 512x512 and bigger?

By the way I am not packing the background images...

Do I have to resort to pixel art and smaller image sizes to create a full fledged sidescroller on android?

I know there are a lot of questions, I'm trying to explain my dilemma so you'll understand it as a whole...
Think of all these questions as 1 question:

Ive been working on this game for 7 months now, knowing that id hav to cross this bridge sometime, I have ALOT done already, i would say the engine is damn near complete, meaning, map/game editor, character mechanics/abilities, game mechanics(level obstacles/things to do, etc), goomba and boss mechanics/abilities/A.I., story, foreground animations(64x64, 64x128 images no problem i.e small file sizes), items, menus, ITs all ready to be used except im having issues with multiple big background sizes....

Please any links, articles, tutorials are appreciated... Ive already gone far enough to know that if im doing something wrong i might have to redo alot of STUFF....

I'm going for a full on 20+ hour side scroller, what do i need to do in terms of gfx in a game that is this huge?

Comment: I've displayed images far larger than that on very low spec devices. Are you sure you're not re-loading the image each frame?

Comment: Yes, theyre only loading once to make sure im understanding what your saying, when i load the texture i use this snippet:    pangodavillageBG01 = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Backgrounds/pangodavillageBG01.png")));                                                -------> pangodavillageBG01.setBounds(0, 0, 25, 25);  Ive put a Gdx.app.log("Loadtexture:", "xxx")  and it only shows it once in the console...

Comment: Do all the background images get drawn even when they're off the screen? I can't see any reason why you should be experiencing such an FPS loss.

Comment: oh damn ur right, i havent implemented any clipping, isnt that what its called "clipping"?  that might just be it, ill start looking around for some info, you wouldnt hav any resource links would ya? tyvm...

Comment: ugh clipping didnt change anything

Comment: Maybe if we saw a sample of your code, then we could help more.

Answer (score 1):

Your drawblocks function is calling new textureregion everytime you call it, you are creating a new object everytime. You should only call new once to create the object and just reference that object when you call drawblocks.

Create some kind of init function you call when you create the screen.

```
TextureRegion block1 = new TextureRegion(blockTextureRegion);
```

Then call in the drawblocks function.

`case 0: spriteBatch.draw(block1, block.getPosition...`

This way you only call new once and not every single time you call drawblocks.

Answer (score 0):

you should read this https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker

use

```
batch.begin();
```

> your sprite render code here

```
batch.end();
```

this will help you in getting higher fps

and texture packer does improve performance use that

Comment: So i packed the images(BGs) with texture packer, ive already been using texture packer with other things just not the backgrounds, and the framerate is hovering under 30 fps,  i should also mention that the images are moving in relation to the player position like a paralax background except it only moves when player moves(im not using the infamous paralax class), i have 8 512x512 images 30kb in size, 4 on one layer, and 4 in front sorta say, also have 250 64x64 8kb tiles displayed on screen plus player, so to me it seems should be running at 60fps... any other ideas? ty guys

Comment: share you rendering code so that i could have a better view of what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Heres the unedited code so u can get an idea, im using WVC method,  heres the main render method, plaz let me know if u want to see the methods that are being called here within..
I know the code needs to be optomized so if there are any major problems you see plz let me know what i should do.. ty

```
public void render() {
 player01_class player01 = world.getPlayer01();

 if ((player01.getPosition().x) > (CAMERA_WIDTH / 2))  {
     cam.position.set((player01.getPosition().x), (cam.position.y), 0);
     //cam.zoom = 3f;
     cam.update();  


 } else if ((player01.getPosition().x) < (CAMERA_WIDTH / 2))  {
     cam.position.set((player01.getPosition().x), (cam.position.y), 0);
     //cam.zoom = 3f;
     cam.update();           
 }

 if ((player01.getPosition().y) > (CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2)) {
     cam.position.set((cam.position.x), (player01.getPosition().y) , 0);
     //cam.zoom = 3f;
     cam.update();  
 } else if ((player01.getPosition().y) < (CAMERA_HEIGHT) / 2) {
     cam.position.set((cam.position.x), (cam.position.y) , 0);
     //cam.zoom = 3f;
     cam.update();  

 }


 clipBounds = new Rectangle(cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y - 10, cam.viewportWidth, cam.viewportHeight);

 ScissorStack.calculateScissors(cam, spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix(), clipBounds, scissors);
 ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);

 spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);  
 spriteBatch.begin();


 //bg_pilot.setPosition(player01.getPosition().x / 1.05f - 10, 0);
 //bg_pilot.draw(spriteBatch, 1f);


 pangodavillageBG_x = player01.getPosition().x;

 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageBG01), pangodavillageBG_x / 1.80f, 2 , 25,  25);   
 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageBG02), pangodavillageBG_x / 1.80f + 25, 2 , 25,  25);  
 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageBG03), pangodavillageBG_x / 1.80f + 50, 2 , 25,  25);  
 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageBG04), pangodavillageBG_x / 1.80f + 75, 2 , 25,  25);  

 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageFG01), pangodavillageBG_x / 2.00f, 0 , 25,  25);   
 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageFG02), pangodavillageBG_x / 2.00f + 25, 0 , 25,  25);  
 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageFG03), pangodavillageBG_x / 2.00f + 50, 0 , 25,  25);  
 spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(pangodavillageFG04), pangodavillageBG_x / 2.00f + 75, 0 , 25,  25);  



// drawClouds();   

 UpdateTime();

 drawBlocks(); 

 //if (controller.edit_toggle)  {
 drawEditBlocks();
 //}

 drawItems(); 

 drawPowerUps();

 drawPlayer01();

 drawBadGuy();

 drawUIItems();



 //stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
// stage.draw();


 bmpfont.draw(spriteBatch, "FPS: " +  Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(),  cam.position.x - 10,  cam.position.y + 7);
 bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "playerX: " + (int)player01.getPosition().x + " Y: " + (int)player01.getPosition().y, cam.position.x - 10,  cam.position.y + 6, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT); 
// bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "rx1: " + rectx1 + " ry1: " + recty1,  cam.position.x - 10,  cam.position.y + 5, 1, HAlignment.LEFT);
// bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "block: " + currentBlock_counter, cam.position.x - 10,  cam.position.y + 5, 1, HAlignment.LEFT);

 //bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "badx: " + badGuy.getPosition().x + " badguyy: " +  badGuy.getPosition().y,  cam.position.x - 10,  cam.position.y + 4, 1, HAlignment.LEFT);    
 //bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "cvelocity: " + badGuy.getAcceleration() + " VBGy: " + badGuy.blockCollidedwithBGY , cam.position.x - 10,  cam.position.y + 3, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT); 
 bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "mouseX: " + mouseX + " Y: " + mouseY  , cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y + 5, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT); 
 //bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "mousexX: " + mouseRawX + " Y: " + mouseRawY  , cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y + 3, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT); 

 bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "camposX: " + (int)cam.position.x + " camposY: " + (int)cam.position.y, cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y + 4, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT);

 bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "H: " + WorldTime_hour + " M: " + WorldTime_min + " S: " + (int)WorldTime_sec, cam.position.x + 6, cam.position.y + 7, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT);

 //bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "TileNumber: " + mapTile_ID + "  block_collide_bool: " +  map_block_collide_bool, cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y + 3, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT); 

 //bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, " aY: " + addButtonRect, cam.position.x, cam.position.y + 2, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT);        
// bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "m: " + rect_mouse + "  a: " + addButtonRect, cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y + 2, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT);      
 //bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "mapTileID: " + mapTile_ID, cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y + 2, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT);        

// bmpfont.drawMultiLine(spriteBatch, "Game Mode: " + edit_toggle , cam.position.x - 10, cam.position.y + 1, 1f, HAlignment.LEFT);      


 spriteBatch.end();

 if (debug) {
     drawDebug();
     //drawCollisionBlocks(); 
    // drawCollisionToggleBlocks();

     drawEditMenu();


}

 spriteBatch.begin();

   //updateParticles();

 spriteBatch.end();

// spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);  
 spriteBatch.begin();

 bmpfont.setScale(.03f); 
 bmpfont.setColor(new Color(1,1,1,1));

 bmpfont.draw(spriteBatch, "ADD", cam.position.x - 9.5f, cam.position.y + 9.65f);
 bmpfont.draw(spriteBatch, "DEL", cam.position.x - 7.9f, cam.position.y + 9.65f);

 bmpfont.draw(spriteBatch, "MODE", cam.position.x - 5.4f, cam.position.y + 9.65f);

 bmpfont.draw(spriteBatch, "BLK", cam.position.x - 2.9f, cam.position.y + 9.65f);
 bmpfont.draw(spriteBatch, "ITM", cam.position.x - 1.35f, cam.position.y + 9.65f);
 bmpfont.draw(spriteBatch, "BAD", cam.position.x - -0.1f, cam.position.y + 9.65f);

 spriteBatch.end();

 spriteBatch.flush();
 ScissorStack.popScissors();


 bmpfont.setColor(new Color(1,1,1,1));
 bmpfont.setScale(.04f);
```

}

heres the drawBlocks method:

```
  private void drawBlocks()  {

   player01_class player01 = world.getPlayer01();


   displayBlock_x[3] = player01.getPosition().x;
   displayBlock_y[3] = cam.position.y + 8;


   for (Block block : world.getBlocks()) {

 //spriteBatch.draw(blockTextureRegion, block.getPosition().x * ppuX, block.getPosition().y * ppuY, Block.SIZE * ppuX, Block.SIZE * ppuY);

   switch (block.blockID)

    {

    case 0:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(blockTextureRegion), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 1:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(blockTextureRegion_metal), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 2:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(btr_basket), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 3:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_sand ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;
    case 4:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_stone1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 5:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_brick ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 6:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_jewel ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 7:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(btr_waterlike), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 8:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(btr_dirtfull1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 9:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_dirtleftside1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 10:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(btr_dirtrightside1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 11:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_dirttop1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 12:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_dirt_leftgrassend1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 13:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_dirt_rightgrassend1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;
    case 14:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_grass1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 15:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(btr_grass_leftend1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 16:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( btr_grass_rightend1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 17:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(btr_grasspatch1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 18:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(sand_full_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());               
    break;

    case 19:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(marble_white_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 20:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(marble_darkwhite_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 21:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stone_darkgrey_2), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 22:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_darkgrey_3 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;
    case 23:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_grey_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 24:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_grey_2 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 25:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stoneinset_grey_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 26:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stoneinset_darkgrey_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 27:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stoneoutset_grey_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 28:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stoneoutset_darkgrey_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 29:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stone_decogrey_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 30:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decodarkgrey_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 31:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decogrey_2 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 32:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decodarkgrey_2 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 33:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decoblue_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 34:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stone_decodarkblue_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 35:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decogreen_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 36:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stone_decodarkgreen_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 37:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stone_decoyellow_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());            
    break;

    case 38:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decodarkyellow_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 39:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decoorange_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 40:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decodarkorange_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;
    case 41:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( stone_decopurple_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 42:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(stone_decodarkpurple_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 43:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion( woodpanel_top_1 ), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 44:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(woodpanel_mid_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   
    break;

    case 45:
          spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(woodpanel_bottom_1), block.getPosition().x , block.getPosition().y , block.getSize(), block.getSize());   

    break;
    }

  }

      if (currentBlock_counter > 45)  {

   currentBlock_counter = 0;

      }

    }
```

and heres the drawPlayer method:

```
private void drawPlayer01()  {
  player01_class player01 = world.getPlayer01();


player01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ? playerIdleLeft : playerIdleRight;

if(player01.getState().equals(State.WALKING)) {

    player01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ?        walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(player01.getStateTime(), true) : 

    walkRightAnimation.getKeyFrame(player01.getStateTime(), true);

} else if (player01.getState().equals(State.JUMPING)) { 

    if (player01.getVelocity().y > 0) { 
        player01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ? player01JumpLeft : player01JumpRight;     
    } else {    
        player01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ? player01FallLeft : player01FallRight;     
    }

}  else if (player01.getState().equals(State.ATTACKING)) {  

    player01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ? playerAtkLeft : playerAtkRight;

}

//spriteBatch.draw(player01Frame, player01.getPosition().x * ppuX, player01.getPosition().y * ppuY, player01.SIZE * ppuX, player01.SIZE * ppuY);

//Attack 
if (player01.boolWeapon_isStriking)  {
    int a = 0;

    player01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ? playerAtkLeft : playerAtkRight;       
    sword01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ? sword01L : sword01R;       

    //if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPressProcessed > 20) {

        if (!player01.isFacingLeft()) {

            player01.weaponPosition.set(player01.getPosition().x + 1, player01.getPosition().y);

        } else if (player01.isFacingLeft()){

            //player01Frame = player01.isFacingLeft() ? sword01L : sword01R;        
            player01.weaponPosition.set(player01.getPosition().x - 1.5f, player01.getPosition().y);

        }

     //spriteBatch.draw(player01Frame, player01.getPosition().x, player01.getPosition().y, player01.getSizeW() , player01.getSizeH() );

     spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(sword01Frame), player01.weaponPosition.x, player01.weaponPosition.y - 0.00f, player01.getWeaponSizeW() , player01.getWeaponSizeH()); 

}

spriteBatch.draw(player01Frame, player01.getPosition().x, player01.getPosition().y, player01.getSizeW() , player01.getSizeH() );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

like someone mentioned before.. Any 'new' statements in draw() method MUST be removed!
It's definitly the cause of your problem!

You have to understand that draw method is called every frame! So if you alocate a Texture of 40kb size multiple times - 60 times per second that is a huge use of memmory bandwidth!

also there are serious memmory leaks there, because every frame you create a texture region and don't call .dispose().

the way you go is to create the texture regions on class init (e.g. In constructor) and store them in private TextureRegion properties an then just use them..

Again no new keyword in whole draw method! This also goes for the new Color(1,1,1,1) .. Use priv property instead and alocate once or use Color.WHITE..

Same goes for all the strings u use! No + of strings alowed.. Also no .toString() e.t.c.

To be paranoid you should not even declare a float/int property in draw.. Create a private aNd reuse...